# what is the class of linear transformations generated by rotations and scaling along one axis

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the class of linear transformations, in 3D or more generally, that are generated by (non-chirality-inverting) rotations and directional scalings? By a "directional scaling" I mean scaling along particular axis, leaving other directions of space untouched. So you could also say: "generated by rotation matrices and by diagonal matrices".

I wouldn't know how to implement a skew in 2D with these primitives, so it's apparently maybe not the class of all linear transformations.

Comment: Do you want a name for these kinds of transformations?

Comment: Note: "non-chirality-inverting" is usually called "orientation-preserving" (i.e. determinant $+1$). But if you also allow arbitrary diagonal matrices, then you get reflections anyway, via the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(-1, +1, \dots, +1)$, so this restriction is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get either all invertible linear transformations this way or all invertible linear transformations with positive determinant depending on whether you allow signs in your diagonal matrices. This follows from the existence of the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which, over $\mathbb{R}$, allows you to write any linear transformation (not necessarily invertible or even square) as a composition $U \Sigma V^T$ where $U, V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with non-negative real entries.

Comment: This is cool... so my intuition about the skew matrix was wrong! I should go look at what the SVD looks like for a skew matrix!